# How to check if I can create a file in a specific folder

Tags: c#, .net, permissions, filesystems

I need to know if I can create a file in a specific folder, but there are too many things to check such as permissions, duplicate files, etc. 
I'm looking for something like `File.CanCreate(@"C:\myfolder\myfile.aaa"`), but haven't found such a method.
The only thing I thought is to try to create a dummy file and check for exceptions but this is an ungly solution that also affects performance.
Do you know a better solution?

Comment: Note, however that checking if you can create a file (however done) and then, later, actually creating the file could still yield an error (you have race-condition here). Thus, it is usually best, just to create the (final) file in the first place and handle possible errors/exceptions.

Comment: You are right but I'm providing this information for later use, I am responsible only of giving this information, if the permissions change after that, another kind of error will be thrown.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In reality, creating a dummy file isn't going to have a huge performance impact in most applications. Of course, if you have advanced permissions with create but not destroy it might get a bit hairy...

Guids are always handy for random names (to avoid conflicts) - something like:

```
string file = Path.Combine(dir, Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".tmp");
// perhaps check File.Exists(file), but it would be a long-shot...
bool canCreate;
try
{
    using (File.Create(file)) { }
    File.Delete(file);
    canCreate = true;
}
catch
{
    canCreate = false;
}
```

Comment: I would like to do it without getting a exception that interrupts debugging (I could tell VS to "hide" it but I'd prefer not to). Is there a way?

Comment: @marc-gravell If the user or the application doesn't have delete permission in the specific folder, a temporary file will remain there in that folder.

Comment: @SyedIrfanAhmad well, yes; if you configure create-only ACLs - weird things can happen; but I maintain: the only way to know that you can *really* create a file is *to create a file*

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CAS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0.aspx) to verify that there are no **.NET policies (caspol)** restricting the creating and writing of a file on that location.

But this will not cover the windows policies. You'll have to manually check the NTFS policies. And even then there are processes that can decide you're not allowed to create a file (for instance a virus scanner).

The best and most complete way is to try it.