# In .NET, check that the current user may write to a directory

Tags: .net, permissions

In .NET, is there a simple way to check whether the current user has access to create a file in a directory? Something equivalent to the C++ _access function, would be ideal.

I don't want to use trial and error (create a dummy file and then delete it): apart from seeming hackish, other software is monitoring the directory in question for dropped files.

I don't want to use System.DirectoryServices: looking at ACL's, resolving group memberships and how permissions from different group memberships interact seems error prone and too hard. There must be a yeah-or-nay function somewhere, no?

Thanks in advance!

[edit] as a bonus, if it would work for a network share as well, that'd be cool.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/265958/284240 Hence handle Exceptions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if I can create a file in a specific folder in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316903/how-to-check-if-i-can-create-a-file-in-a-specific-folder-in-c)

Comment: check this answer, to convert it in VB.NET should be trivial ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/a/130641/559144

Comment: re: handle exceptions -- I agree entirely; except I am tasked to write a script that ensures the system is configured correctly, not guard an operation that may fail. I want to do so without doing using trial and error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
FileIOPermission writePermission = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, filename);
if (SecurityManager.IsGranted(writePermission)){
    //write here
} else {
    //some error message
}
```

Comment: Assuming it works (I hope), one of those answers that makes me upvote, upvote the question, and favourite it :)

Comment: Looks great! Let me try it out.

Comment: It does not seem to work for me. For some reason it always returns true. It must be something I'm doing wrong, but it is so straight forward, I don't see what it would be. /sigh... I've marked it as accepted, because it points me to the right API's. I just have to work it out, I guess

Comment: It seems SecurityManager.IsGranted does not apply to non-CAS permissions, so this doesn't work. :(

Comment: `SecurityManager.IsGranted()` is deprecated:
"'SecurityManager.IsGranted(IPermission)' is obsolete: 'IsGranted is obsolete and will be removed in a future release of the .NET Framework.  Please use the PermissionSet property of either AppDomain or Assembly instead.'"

Answer (score 6):

Checking for permission in advance is a dicey project. Not to mention complicated, running through the entire ACL list and computing the effective permission set.

Further...there are no guarantees. Just because you proactively checked for permission ahead of time doesn't mean that the permissions won't have changed at the moment you try to create the file.

The "right" way is to make a [security demand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720254%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), either declaratively with [`FileIOPermissionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermissionattribute%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) or imperatively, by creating an appropriate instance of [`FileIOPermission`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission.aspx) and invoking its [`Demand()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.codeaccesspermission.demand.aspx) method. If you have the desired permissions, the call to `Demand()` succeeds; otherwise it throws a `SecurityException`, which you'll need to catch and act on.

In my experience, the imperative check is easier.

It should also be noted that in Windows 7, while you might conceptually have write access to the directory, it still might not work unless you're running with elevated permissions.

Comment: I agree entirely. I wouldn't want to check permissions to guard an operation that might fail. We have a legacy system that has many pieces of software that run on many servers and are hounded by admin/config issues. I need to write an app that goes through looking for configuration errors, but must do so passively, with no chance of orphaning test/dummy files or the like.

Answer (score 0):

The following will return a DirecotrySecurity instance http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.directorysecurity.aspx

```
DirectoryInfo(pathstr).GetAccessControl()
```

Comment: Does this apply to the current user? I looked at this and it seemed to give access to the ACL. It may say that the "Foo Managers" user group has write access and "Bar Workers" is denied, but does not help me resolve whether the current user is a member of a group that is a member of one of these groups. Maybe I miss how to resolve that bit